# Setting up pusher_client with laravel_echo

Tags: flutter, laravel-echo

Im currently making a app that needs to have live updates,
Im using pusher_client: ^2.0.0 and laravel_echo: ^0.2.2. I created a function which I call on initState :

````
    PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
      host: 'reservegcc.com',
      wsPort: 6001,
      encrypted: false,
    );

    PusherClient pusher = PusherClient('11111', options, autoConnect: false);
    Echo echo = Echo({
      'broadcaster': 'pusher',
      'client': pusher,
      "wsHost": 'reservegcc.com',
      "wsPort": 6001,
      "disableStats": true,
      'wssPort': 6001,
      'forceTLS': true,
      'enabledTransports': ['ws', 'wss']
    });
    echo.channel('restaurant-transactions').listen('Transaction', (e) {
      print(e);
    });
    echo.connector.pusher.onConnectionStateChange((state) {
      print(state!.currentState.toString());
    });
    echo.connector.pusher.connect();
  }```

Im getting connecting and reconning on the onConnectionStateChange, Can someone please help me what is lacking on my code. I have done a lot of research but still cannot connect.
````

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me (I am using laravel_flutter_pusher: ^0.0.4):

```
void setUpServices() {
    var options = PusherOptions(
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 6001,
        encrypted: false,
        cluster: 'pusher-cluster',
    );

    LaravelFlutterPusher pusher = LaravelFlutterPusher('pusher-key', options, enableLogging: true);
    pusher
        .subscribe('public')
        .bind('news', (event) => log('event =>$event'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro I have spent a lot of time on this subject and I discovered a weird issue that the pusher package doesn't affect when you hot restart / reload the project. So you must exit and debug your project again and review the result of your changes.

And another hand I didn't use the echo package and I wrote channel and event names manually like this;

```
_pusher.subscribe("private-user.call.$userId").bind(
  "App\\Events\\callUser",
  (PusherEvent event) {
    var data = jsonDecode(event.data);
    switch (data["type"]) {
      case "bla bla":
        // do something
        break;
      case "bla bla":
        // do something
        break;
    }
  },
);
```